# Bluetooth on Linux - are there alternatives to bluez

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluez

I have pretty bad experience with bluez (sometimes it works, sometimes not), but are there any alternatives or scripts ? I want to connect Ubuntu to iPhone without Bluetooth passkey because I don't have GUI.

Comment: AFAIK none. bluez works fine for the five different devices that I have. The issues you have might be down to the Linux BT drivers, not necessarily bluez. It makes sense to give bluez bug tracker a visit anyways and report your issues. Lots of smart folks over there and they may help you fix kernel issues as well. https://github.com/bluez/bluez/issues

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.